# Finding the inverse of $y = x\ln\left(\frac m{1-x}+1\right)$ where $0<x<1$ and $m > 0$

Tags: functions, inverse

Find the inverse of $y = x\ln\left(\frac{m}{1-x}+1\right)$ where $0<x<1$ and $m > 0$.

[Thanks for editing my question] :)

Thanks,

Comment: ...please...?...

Comment: Where did this problem come from?

Comment: Such equations relating both $x$ and $\ln(x)$ are either trivial or lead to the use of the $W$ function, or even worse. I tried yours on maple, which usually finds $W$ function solutions, and it failed to find one. Probably the best you can do is a series solution, or other approximating function to the inverse.

Comment: @coffeemath thanks for your reply! I think alike. I tried the W function myself, but can't get it well in the form to apply W. :(

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal a computer science problem that reduces to solve an inverse problem. :)

Comment: @DonAntonio sorry don't quite get it, what do you mean?

Comment: Basically, @90b56587, two things: (1) One needs to be more polite when asking for something from other people, and more important (2) we expect here to be shown by the asker some self work, some idea, background, etc. about his/her question.